# Installing NetworkManager without internet connection

Tags: fedora, networkmanager

I have a slight problem, I uninstalled my Network Manager in Fedora Core 15, why I did this was because it did not show anymore, I thought I will re-install it using my wireless connection but I now can't connect to my wireless connection any longer, is there a way to install Network Manager to that Pc without any Internet Connection by using a RPM file that I can download from my other PC and then install it to my no internet pc, so that it can work again?

Also what steps can I take if this is not possible to get Network Manager installed again?

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: 32bit Operating system

Comment: Boot live usb, chroot couple folders like /proc, /root (forget what else) , make sure you are connected , and do yum install network-manager.

Answer (score 1):

Download whatever RPMs you need from a repository such as [RedHat's](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/updates/15/). Then burn them to CD or put them on a USB key.

Comment: ,the problem is I do not know which RPM's I need to install this , since the RPM for Network Manager Gnome has some dependencies, but I've managed this morning to get to a lan connection which works and thus installed Network Manager, thx for the help anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you have a a wire to connect to the Internet, you can connect through the command line, using `dhclient eth0` on the command line (you need to be root). Once connected just `yum install NetworkManager`.  NetworkManager is case sensistive.